# How can I stop my workflow from running straight though and completing? SharePoint designer workflow 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer

So I have this issue that I seemed to have inherited, and it is really starting to get me down. The thing is, I have this flow going on for an approval, that doesn't use the OOB Task list.

Ok, no problem, right? The thing is, there is this one field if it Pending, then send this email, then wait for this item to be approved by looking for this other field over here to be equal to yes, like so:

[image]

The thing is, if the item is rejected, the field is set to no. So it never gets past the wait statement.

When I take it out completely, it shoots though the entire workflow and completes, with only sending out the first 3 emails shown above.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: Instead of a Wait for the change of a column, wait for the item to change (any change), and then in an IF check the Approval Status.

Option 2: Create a workflow just to check the Approval Status. Let the workflow fire on change. On each change, check to see if the Approval Status is set to Yes or No, and if so, do the needed work, and if not, just exit. Non-approval edits will trigger the workflow, but it will just exit without doing work.

We often create multiple workflows that fire on change, check for the one thing they do, and then exit. One of the benefits is that you don't have long running workflows.